# Java program starts and stops without doing anything

Tags: java, performance

I'm trying to make a little, basic game of Nim. I'm a beginner in java. When I run the code, it just runs for a second, and stops without doing what I ask of it. It's probably a simple solution but I had to ask. Does anyone have any idea? Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Nim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int playernum;
        int cpunum = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
        int gamenum = 21;
        boolean win = false;
        boolean turn = true;

        while((win = false) && (turn = true)){
            System.out.println("The number is 21. Enter a number from 1 - 3");
            playernum = input.nextInt();

            int remaining = gamenum - playernum;

            System.out.println("The number is now " + remaining);
            turn = false;

            if((turn = false) && (gamenum > 0)){
                System.out.println("Computer is thinking...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Use `==` for comparison, `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: This is why you should always check `!turn` instead of `turn == false`.

Comment: `while( !win && turn)`  change to this and try

Comment: Oh thanks so much. Used your suggestion and it worked. So `while( !win && turn)` is the same as `while((win == false) && ( turn == true))` but just more effiecient?

Comment: It's the same but a better, more concise way of writing it. In terms of efficiency however, they are more or less the same.

Comment: It's just easier to read. It's also interesting to note the exact reason that your code doesn't work. For future reference, the 'return value' (so to speak) of an assignment operation is the value on the right side of the `=`. In the condition of the while loop, `while((win = false) && ...)` the entire `(win = false)` evaluates to just `false` while assigning that value to `win`, so you get `while(false && ...)`. The loop is never entered.

Comment: It's also redundant. You're checking the boolean result of a comparison of boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

When using boolean variables in if statements and loop headers, there's no need to check if they equal `true` or `false`, just use the variables themselves like so,

```
while(!win && turn){
    System.out.println("The number is 21. Enter a number from 1 - 3");
    playernum = input.nextInt();

    int remaining = gamenum - playernum;

    System.out.println("The number is now " + remaining);
    turn = false;

    if(!turn && gamenum > 0){
    System.out.println("Computer is thinking...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Also, another issue before was that when you were checking the boolean variables you were using the wrong operator `=`. You should have used `==` to compare equality between primitive types but with booleans it's not necessary. If you wanna check if a boolean variable is `true`, just use the boolean variable itself as the condition. And if you wanna check if a boolean variable is 'false', just use the negation of the boolean variable by using the `!` operator in the condition.